# Openstreetmap Amazon EBS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openstreetmap

Has anybody had any luck using Openstreetmap Amazon EBS ?

I just could not start Postgres, having created it using

```
 pg_createcluster --locale=en_US -d /openstreetmap/data/ 8.3 osm
```

and then running it

```
pg_ctlcluster 8.3 osm start
```

Error:

```
Error: The server must be started under the locale : which does not exist any more.

Running locale -a on my ec2 (AMI ID: ami-b7aa4cde)
  C
  de_DE
  en_US
  en_US.utf8
  en_US.utf-8
  en_US.UTF-8
  hu_HU
  hu_HU.utf8
  POSIX
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Few pointers:

1. Have to mount the EBS under /mnt/sdm , otherwise I have to modify the config file.
2. I had no luck running it as a new cluster, so I just replaced the data directory in the default postgresql install dir with the /mnt/sdm
3. Had to create data/pg_log and /var/run/postgresql directories.
4. Had to increase kernel shared memory parameters so postgres can run
5. Had to use x64 version of postgres
6. Had to use postgres compiled with HAVE_64BIT_TIMESTAMP

Due to all these problems, I am just getting a fresh dump from openstreet planet, and hopefully can import it into my database.